# THH of the tensor product of E_1 rings

Tags: homotopy-theory, higher-algebra

Is there a formula or a spectral sequence relating the $THH$ of two $E_1$-rings and the $THH$ of their tensor product over $\mathbb{S}$? Krause and Nikolaus state without context on page 3 of their paper ([Bokstedet's periodicity and quotients of DVRs](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.03477.pdf)) that $$THH(A) \otimes_{\mathbb{S}} THH(B) = THH(A \otimes_{\mathbb{S}} B).$$ It might be that they suppressed the requirement that $A$ and $B$ are $E_\infty$-rings, but I was wondering if there's something like that for $E_1$-rings in general?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The category of $E_1$-algebra spectra admits a symmetric monoidal structure given by the smash product. Viewed as a functor $Alg(Sp) \rightarrow CycSp$, THH is symmetric monoidal.  This claim essentially boils down to the fact that sifted colimits commute with the smash product. This is noted at the beginning of IV.2 of Nikolaus-Scholze. If one wishes to fully unpack the claim in the HA language, looking at HA 3.2.4 might be helpful.

Comment: One way to think about it is that THH(A)=dim(LMod(A)) where the symmetric monoidal dimension is taken in Pr_st (presentable stable infitnity-categories). Since symmetric monoidal dimension is multiplicative in general and since LMod(-) is symmetric monoidal w.r.t. the tensor product of associative algebras and tensor product of presentable categories, THH is symmetric monoidal.

Comment: Absolutely! I love the POV of THH as the trace of dualizable objects in Pr^L_St; it makes claims like this automatic.

Comment: @LiamKeenan Thank you! I will try to work out the details.

Comment: This was also known for S-algebras (in the sense of EKMM) since the early days of the subject and the proof is easy (see Lemma 3.1 in "Topological Hochschild homology" by Schwänzl-Vogt-Waldhausen).